# Equivalence of Definitions of Order of Zero

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following definition:

Given a function $f$ that is holomorphic in some domain $\Omega$ (nonempty connected open subset of the complex plane), if for some $z_{0} \in \Omega$, we have that $f(z_{0})=0$ and that $$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}\left ( \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_{0})^{n}} \right )$$

Exists and is nonzero, then we say that $z_{0}$ is a zero of order $m$.

I've been doing some reading and apparently an equivalent definition is the following:

Let $f$ anf $z_{0}$ be as given above, then $z_{0}$ is a zero of order $n$ if $$f(z_{0})=f'(z_{0})=f''(z_{0})=...=f^{(n-1)}(z_{0})$$

But $f^{n}(z_{0})\neq 0$

I'm having trouble seeing how the first definition leads to the second (much more intuitive), definition.
I imagine this might involve induction on $n$, and I've formulated a base case.
If $n=1$, the definition of derivative at a point, the assumption that $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}\left ( \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_{0})} \right )$ exists and is non-zero and the fact that $f(z_{0})=0$ immediately imply that $f'(z_{0})\neq 0$.

Now I assume that for some n, we have that $f(z_0)=0$ and $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}\left ( \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_{0})^{n}} \right )$ exists and is nonzero implies that $f(z_{0})=f'(z_{0})=f''(z_{0})=...=f^{(n-1)}(z_{0})$ and $f^{(n)}(z_0) \neq 0$

Now I have to show that this leads to the following: If $f(z_0)=0$ and $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}\left ( \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_{0})^{n+1}} \right )$ exists and is nonzero, then $f(z_{0})=f'(z_{0})=f''(z_{0})=...=f^{(n)}(z_{0})$ and $f^{(n+1)}(z_0) \neq 0$

Showing this implication is where I'm having a lot of trouble. I suspect I'll have to apply Taylor's Theorem, but I really can't see how to do so. I'd really appreciate any hints, help or ideas, thanks!

Comment: If $f(z)$ is **analytic** around $z_0$ then for $|z-z_0|$ small enough $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!} (z-z_0)^n$. If $f(z)$ is not identically zero then there is $k$ such that $f^{(k)}(z_0) \ne 0, f^{(n)}(z_0)=0$ for $0 \le n < k$. This is the order of the zero at $z_0$.  Letting $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^k}$ it is analytic around $z_0$ and $g(z_0) = \frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!} $. Finally, we use the holomorphic $\implies$ analytic theorem.

Comment: I follow the first half of your answer, but at the definition of g I get a little confused. I don't quite see how this relates to my limit definition, and it seems the implication is in the wrong direction. I'd really appreciate it if you'd expand your comment to an answer with a little more explanation. Thanks for the help do far!

Comment: The limit is $g(z_0) \overset{def}=\lim_{z \to z_0} g(z) = \lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^k} = \frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!}$. In complex analysis whenever it is possible we extend a function continuously, e.g. $h(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z}, h(0) = 1$